# Implementing Linked List in java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement linked list in java, but nothing gets printed out. I tried debugging it and it seems that every time the Add function gets called the previous value gets over written. However when i check the logic of it, it should work.

```
public class MyLinkedList {

public Node head;
public Node curr;

public MyLinkedList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    head = null;
    curr = null;
}

public void Add(int data) {
    Node box = new Node();
    box.data = data;
    box.next = null;
    curr = head;
    if (curr == null) {
        head = box;
        curr = null;
    }

    else {
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;

        }
        curr.next = box;
    }
}

public void Print() {
    curr = head;
    while (curr != null) {
        System.out.println(curr.data);
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
}
```

This is what the Node class has

```
public class Node {
    public int data;
   public Node next;
}
```

Comment: where is the code that runs the `Print` method?

Comment: Show full example. How you use it, calling add and print.

Comment: One note is that `public Node curr;` should be a local variable in all cases.

Comment: It has a lot of style and other problems, but it does work: http://ideone.com/XoLY1P

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling your class, i.e. show us your test class.

Comment: Its working already

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Just go and delete *.class files. It may be stuck in early stages of your code.
 *.class files located under output folder (name of the folder can change depending on the IDE you used but generally under build folder.) you may need to delete that folder completely.

Answer (score 0):

It works already, but I'll tidy it up for you:

```
public class MyLinkedList {

    private Node head; //never expose a field as public

    //the whole constructor was unnecessary

    public void add(int data) { //methods start with a lower case
        add(new Node(data)); //nodes always need data, so I'm passing in constructor
    }

    // this method adds an existing node rather than the previous add both
    // creating, finding the end and adding
    private void add(Node node) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            lastNode().next = node;
        }
    }

    private Node lastNode() { //finds the last node in the chain
        Node curr = head; //curr is local
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return curr;
    }

    public void print() { //methods start with a lower case
        Node curr = head; //curr is local
        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.println(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    private static class Node { //this class is just useful internally to MyLinkedList
        private final int data; //final - node data doesn't change
        private Node next;

        private Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.